# How to delete something not in the join of 2 tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ive got a problem where I want to delete orphaned records. I was wondering what the syntax is for deleting records that aren't in a join.

So if my query to get the stuff (that I dont want to delete is):

```
select * from tbl_user tu
inner join tbl_user_group_xref tugx on tu.userid=tugx.userid
```

Then how do I 
1) get the stuff that isnt in the clause and  2) delete it?

Like to do it without using arrays but an array solution would still be useful for learning purposes.

Comment: Which table are you trying to delete from?

Comment: "something not in the join of 2 tables" is known as an [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29).

Comment: good info thanks, @duncan im not deleting from a table im deleting everything not in the join.

Comment: hi, Pete. could you check if the query offered by fsb is composed well and satisfies to your objective? if it does, i'd advice to use it rather than one offered by me. the thing is that IN operation is more expensive than JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an optimization to Duncan Howe's answer that I know works in MySQL and may work with other servers. It probably also works for t-clausen.dk's answer in MySQL.

If you are deleting rows from table t1 that don’t have corresponding rows in t2 and both tables are very large then the server can end up getting swamped with disk seeks. I found that performance can be improved a lot if you can force the server to load t2's index into memory before running the query and then, in the query, force the server to ignore t1's index. That makes the server do a sequential scan of t1, which will be an efficient use of disk. The server steps through each row of t1 looking up t2's index, which is in memory, to determine if the row should be deleted. The disk seeks are thus eliminated and disk IO rate is very high, which keeps the CPU busy.

For example:

```
delete tbl_user 
  from tbl_user tu ignore key (primary)
  left join tbl_user_group_xref tugx 
    use key (userid) on tu.userid=tugx.userid
where tugx.userid is null
```

(I'm assuming that `tbl_user.userid` is its table's PK and the index on `tbl_user_group_xref.userid` is named `userid`. If not, change the respective key names.)

Forcing a server to load an index into memory is technology-specific. In MySQL for MyISAM tables you can use `load index into cache`. Recreating an index from scratch (which is very fast in MySQL) might leave it in cache (and would have the nice side effect of balancing the  B-tree).

I've seen examples with well over 100x improvement using this optimization. So long as you can cache t2's index, you can process very large tables efficiently.

Comment: This is probably the most underrated answer on all of Stack Overflow. Kudos, @user213154!

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
delete tbl_user 
  from tbl_user tu 
  left join tbl_user_group_xref tugx on tu.userid=tugx.userid 
where tugx.userid is null
```

Comment: this is a good answer but I think I prefer heximals answer as its more expressive

Comment: @Pete2k, you should accept this answer. It is properly scalable and fast while heximal's will generate a potentially very large temp table.

Comment: I don't know T-SQL intimately but the MySQL manual gives finding orphan rows as an example of what you might use `left join` for. But the formatting of your SQL could have been better!

Comment: this performs way better than Heximal's code and I can recommand using this script or mine.

Answer (score 6):

e.g.:

```
delete from tbl_user tu
where 
  user_id not in (
    select 
      user_id 
    from 
      tbl_user tu
    inner join 
      tbl_user_group_xref tugx on tu.userid=tugx.userid
)
```

Comment: you have not joined your tables tbl_user with the subselect, making it slow if there are alot of users.

Comment: It is a pity that this was accepted because it would be better to learn what a `left loin` is, how it differs form `inner join` and why it is very useful than to encourage anyone to use a subquery as inefficient as this one. Anyone who cares about performance should compare the efficiency of this to that of Duncan Howe's or t-clausen.dk's answers.

Comment: Maybe one of the "Gods" will change it. This is really a classic mistake, so sad to see it "win"

Comment: i've post a comment to a question and adviced the author to change his mind and accept your answer. hope, he'll read it

Answer (score 2):

This delete statement performs optimal as well as the script from Duncan Howe. I gave Duncan Howe a plus because it is correct and I didn't know that syntax.

```
delete tu
from tbl_user tu 
where not exists (select 1 from tbl_user_group_xref where userid = tu.userid)
```

Comment: The `left join ___ where ___ is null` that Duncan Howe gave is a perfectly good solution. Down voted for "the only correct way" which and good engineer should know is usually not factual. Otherwise I prefer this to the `not in (subquery)` which seems problematic.

Comment: "the best answer" is a judgement that could be defended while "the only correct way" is simply not correct and makes an otherwise good answer wrong. Remove that comment and I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: avoid 'not in (subquery)', I wrote about it on my blog, my sql performs better.

Comment: Agreed re: `not in (subquery)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NOT IN statement like described here http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php

Basically you would write a select query from the table where you would like to delete records from and then perform a NOT IN on a subquery that joins the two tables.

I don't know if this is very good performance wise though.

Edit: basically exactly what Heximal says.